# is this way to in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

in my app i want to give facility of posting an advertisement through in-App purchase. for posting one advertisement user has to paid 0.99$ ( i.e. default 1 tier for india) through the In-App purchase. once he made purchase through the in -App purchase then he able to post advertisement. then for next advertisement post he has to made again new purchase.

also user can purchase credits through in-app purchase. user can purchase 100 credits in 9$, 1000 credits in 80$. then user can use these credits to post an Advertisement. for posting one advertisement user need 10 credits

is Apple Allow to do this.  or should I use Paypal for this.

can apple allow me to use paypal system for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple's policy would allow this. Real world items (like the adverts you are selling) can't be purchased through iAP. A payment system should be used like Paypal or ZooZ. And yes, Apple allow these payment systems to be used for almost anything.

Hope this helps, 
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fine. It would be one token per post, which as long as it's offered inside the app, it seems to meet all the guidelines.

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf